# what is wrong in this query. It is giving me syntax error on or near TRUNCATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am making a postgresSql function to return all rows from a temp table. I want to delete all rows from table in starting of my function But it is giving me syntax error on or near TRUNCATE. 
This is my query -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.monthly_data_of_antenatal_care(hospitalId integer)
  RETURNS SETOF antenatal_care_temp AS $$
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM antenatal_care_temp group by hospital_id,antenatal_temp_id;
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE antenatal_care_temp RESTART IDENTITY;
FOR 
  select hospital_id from mas_hospital where parent_institute_id = $1 or hospital_id = $1
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      'insert into table antenatal_care_temp(total,bpl,sc,st,below_19,jsy_reg,early_reg,high_risk_an,prophylaxis_i,prophylaxis_c1,prophylaxis_c2,treatment_i,
treatment_c1,treatment_c2,an_checkups_1,an_checkups_2,an_checkups_3,an_checkups_4,an_checkups_5,tt_a_1,tt_i_1,tt_a_2,tt_i_2,data_type) values(
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where Extract(month from reg_date) = Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where bpl_status = 'Y' and Extract(month from reg_date) = Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19  and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey where jsy_flag = 'Yes' and Extract(month from reg_date) = Extract(month from now())  and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where complication != '' and Extract(month from reg_date) = Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,0,0
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) = Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1)
'current',
$1
);

insert into table antenatal_care_temp(total,bpl,sc,st,below_19,jsy_reg,early_reg,high_risk_an,prophylaxis_i,prophylaxis_c1,prophylaxis_c2,treatment_i,
treatment_c1,treatment_c2,an_checkups_1,an_checkups_2,an_checkups_3,an_checkups_4,an_checkups_5,tt_a_1,tt_i_1,tt_a_2,tt_i_2,data_type) values(
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where Extract(month from reg_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where bpl_status = 'Y' and Extract(month from reg_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey where jsy_flag = 'Yes' and Extract(month from reg_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from  ph_anc_survey where complication != '' and Extract(month from reg_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and Extract(year from reg_date) = Extract(year from now()) and hospital_id = $1),
0,0,0
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1),
0,
(select count(*) from ph_anc_survey pas join ph_anc_followup paf on pas.anc_reg_id = paf.anc_reg_id  where paf.age < 19 and Extract(year from paf.followup_date) = Extract(year from now()) and Extract(month from paf.followup_date) between 4 and Extract(month from now()) and pas.hospital_id = $1)
'cumulative',
$1
)';
   END LOOP;
END
$$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: I guess no TABLE keyword after TRUNCATE should solve this ?

Comment: `language SQL` doesn't support `execute` (or `begin ...end`) You need `language plpgsql`. You also can't have a `select before the first `begin`. And the select also needs a target on where to store that data. I also don't think you can run two statements with a single `execute`. And neither of those `inserts` have a `returning` clause, so they won't return any data.

Comment: The whole function seems overly complex and doing inserts in a a loop is a guarantee for slow performance. Why don't you just use an `insert ... select` directly? Maybe if you explained us what your **real** problem is, we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: i want to insert data in a temp table on different conditions. but i also want that each time when i call this function it should delete all rows from the table then it should insert in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your function that it is hard to know where to start. It is also impossible to give you a correct solution because your `INSERT` statements have more columns than the `VALUES` clause.

Some basic points:

- Learn [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html). This should solve many of the syntactical issues, like a `SELECT` statement before `BEGIN`.
- If your function `RETURNS SETOF something` you do not need to first populate a temporary table. Preferably you should `RETURN SETOF something`, use a temporary table when the data to be returned is (potentially) very large, but then you would specify `RETURNS void` (or possibly the temp table name). However, if you get rid of the temporary table altogether you should specify `RETURNS TABLE (f1 int, f2 int, ...)`.
- In the function body, take as much computation out of the loop as you can.
- Don't create humongous `INSERT` statement that you yourself don't understand anymore and which is killing your performance (in both `INSERT` statements you produce a number 14 times with the same sub-queries!). Break it down into manageable chunks.

You should produce a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.monthly_data_of_antenatal_care(hospitalId integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (total int, bpl int, sc int, st int, below_19 int, ....) AS $$
DECLARE
    hid        integer;
    this_month timestamp;
    cnt        integer;
    fup        integer;
BEGIN
    this_month = date_trunc('month', now()); -- Outside of the loop
    FOR hid IN
        SELECT hospital_id FROM mas_hospital
        WHERE parent_institute_id = $1 OR hospital_id = $1
    LOOP
        SELECT count(*) INTO cnt
        FROM ph_anc_survey
        WHERE date_trunc('month', reg_date) = this_month AND hospital_id = hid;

        SELECT count(*) INTO fup
        FROM ph_anc_survey pas JOIN ph_anc_followup paf USING (anc_reg_id)
        WHERE paf.age < 19 AND date_trunc('month', paf.followup_date) = this_month
          AND pas.hospital_id = hid;
        -- More statements like above

        RETURN NEXT VALUES (cnt, fup, 0, ...); -- Must match structure of RETURNS TABLE
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```